# Why does this generate a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

```
#include<stdio.h>
void foo(int **arr) {
    arr[1][1]++;
}

main() {
    int arr[20][20];
    printf("%d\n",arr[1][1]);
    foo((int**)arr);
    printf("%d\n",arr[1][1]);
}
```

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by that cast?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Suppose you declare:
>       int arr[ 10 ][ 20 ] ;
>     What type is arr?
>   You may think that it's `int **`, but that's incorrect.
>
> Its actually of type `int (*)[20]` when it decays (like when you pass it to a function);
>   **Array decaying applies only once.**

[**Details here**](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html)

---

Now consider the following,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void foo(int arr[][20]) {
  arr[1][1]++;
}
main() {
  int (*arr)[20];
  arr = malloc(sizeof(int (*)[]) * 2); //2 rows & malloc will do implicit cast.

  printf("%d\n",arr[1][1]);
  foo(arr);
  printf("%d\n",arr[1][1]);
}
```

Output :

> $ gcc fdsf.c && ./a.out
>   0
>   1

---

> **arr** and **arr+1** are pointing to array of 20 integers.
>
> arr + 0 --> int       int       int    ...    int (20 ints, contiguous)
>                [0][0]   [0][1]
>   arr + 1 --> int       int       int    ...    int (20 ints, contiguous)
>                [1][0]   [1][1]

Comment: It's actually of type `int[10][12]`, although it decays to `int(*)[10]`. Look at `sizeof(arr)` to see this.

Comment: Doesn't it decay to `int(*)[12]`?

Comment: @UncleBens: Good point. Look at `sizeof *arr` to see this ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Here's what an `int[2][2]` looks like in memory:

`int[2] int[2]`

That is, an array immediately followed by another array.

Here's what an `int[2]` looks like in memory:

`int int`

That is, an int immediately followed by another int.

So, here's also what an `int[2][2]` looks like in memory:

```
int int int int
     ^       ^
     |       |___ this is arr[1][1]
     |
     |____ this is p[1], assuming sizeof(int*) == sizeof(int)
```

If you cast `arr` to an `int**`, I'm going to call the result `p`. Then it points to the same memory. When you do `p[1][1]` you don't get `arr[1][1]`. What the program does instead is, it reads the value at `p[1]`, adjusts that up by the size of an int, and *dereferences it*. If that second int contained, say, the value "21" then you have just tried to dereference the pointer "25" (if `int` is 4 bytes). That ain't right.

Arrays are not the same as pointers, and 2-D arrays are certainly not the same thing as pointers-to-pointers.

Answer (score 6):

Because foo expect a pointer to a pointer to int and you are passing it a pointer to an array of 20 int.  Casting it won't change the fact that it isn't the correct type.

Answer (score 5):

If you change it like this, you get the expected result:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void foo(int arr[][20]) {
    arr[1][1]++;
}

int
main() {
    int arr[20][20];
    arr[1][1] = 1;
    printf("%d\n",arr[1][1]);
    foo(arr);
    printf("%d\n",arr[1][1]);
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but you don't have to put the first dimension.

Answer (score 4):

`foo` needs to know the array size (well, at least the second array dimension, first isn't needed), otherwise it can't do the necessary pointer arithmetic for the `[1][1]`.

Comment: John, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Yes, I'd also like to know why this is wrong, when I am certain that it is not, and all the other answers say the same thing...

Comment: Well, the compiler isn't segfaulting because it is missing information about one of the array's dimensions. It's segfaulting because it's dereferencing where it shouldn't be. If `arr` were a true `int**` ragged array then the compiler would not need to know the size of either dimension, nor would it crash when accessing the array items.

If the OP had written `void foo(int arr[][])` and gotten a compile error about a missing dimension then your answer would be correct. As is it is only the tip of the iceberg. @Steve Jessop explains better why the program crashes, IMO.

Comment: Well obviously it's segfaulting because it's accessing the wrong memory - that's what a segfault is. The real question is why it's accessing the wrong memory in the first place, and that's because he's getting the types mixed up.

Comment: I think this answer goes some way towards explaining what you actually need to do in order to pass a 2-D array as a function parameter. That is, *what's wrong with the questioner's code* to cause the crash. What I explained is *what the wrong code does* that causes the crash: a more proximate cause.

Comment: You could say this answer is incomplete (I would argue most of the others are too), but it's not wrong.  Poita didn't say you can never pass arrays of pointers, or that the OP's code caused a compiler (as opposed to run-time) error.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that `int arr[20][20]` for 2d array means that this array is stored as 1d array, and lines are stored one after other. when you do indexing to `int **arr` you actually take 2nd element from first line of array, then you dereference it and take first element there.