# Function pointer to function returning Multidimensional array

Tags: c, function-pointers

With respect to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529041/decayed-multidimensional-array-return-from-function) question, we can declare a function that returns pointer to array as:

```
int (*function())[3]
```

which returns Ax3 array, ok.

How is the proper way to declare a function pointer that points this kind of function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps

```
int (*(*function_pointer)())[3];
```

(at least gcc seems to understand it)

Answer (score 3):

```
        f                 -- f
       *f                 -- is a pointer
      (*f)()              -- to a function
     *(*f)()              -- that returns a pointer
    (*(*f)())[3]          -- to a 3-element array 
int (*(*f)())[3]          -- of int
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this reference](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html), which is quite helpful. Note the techniques using typedefs

```
typedef int (*pfintarray())[3];

pfintarray myFunc() { /* etc
```