# How to get length of char**?

Tags: c, arrays

Quick c question: How to know the length of a char* foo[]?

Thanks.

Comment: `char **foo` is not same as `char *foo[]` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448204/why-does-this-generate-a-segmentation-fault/2448255#2448255

Comment: The question makes no sense without context. `char* foo[]` might mean completely different things in different contexts.

Comment: Your question needs to be clarified. Asking for the length/size of char*[] usually assumes the answer is the number of char* elements in the array. Asking for the size of char** usually assume the answer is the size of a pointer. Asking for the length of a char* assumes the answer is the size of the memory from the pointer value to the first '\x0' character. (And of course, you might actually be asking about the total allocated memory consumed by all the strings in the array :-)) So which one is it?

Comment: Evan mentioned that you can if it's null-terminated. Even if it's terminated with something else, but you know what that something is, you can find the length. Otherwise not without additional information about it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't.  Not without knowing something about what is inside of the pointers, or storing that data ahead of time.

Comment: +1, though I wonder how many reincarnations of this very question will be answered without pointing to numerous duplicates.

Answer (score 7):

You mean the number of strings in the array?

If the array was allocated on the stack in the same block, you can use the `sizeof(foo)/sizeof(foo[0])` trick.

```
const char *foo[] = { "abc", "def" };
const size_t length = sizeof(foo)/sizeof(foo[0]);
```

If you're talking about the `argv` passed to main, you can look at the `argc` parameter.

If the array was allocated on the heap or passed into a function (where it would decay into a pointer), you're out of luck unless whoever allocated it passed the size to you as well.

Answer (score 3):

If the array is statically allocated you can use the `sizeof()` function. So `sizeof(foo)/sizeof(char *)` would work.
If the array was made dynamically, you're in trouble! The length of such an array would normally be explicitly stored.

EDIT:
janks is of course right, `sizeof` is an operator.

Also it's worth pointing out that C99 does allow `sizeof` on variable-size arrays. However different compilers implement different parts of C99, so some caution is warranted.

Comment: sizeof is an operator, not a function.  Using sizeof on an expression (as opposed to the name of a type) doesn't even require braces.